# Only when the function is odd its Fourier coefficient of cosnx is equal to 0?

Tags: fourier-analysis

[image]
Only when the function is odd  its Fourier coefficient of  cosnx is equal to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your function is the sum of a constant and an odd function. Because of the constant, $a_0\ne0$, so not all $a_n$ are zero. But the ones for $n\ge1$ do vanish, because $a_n$ for $n\ge1$ vanish both in the case of a constant and for odd functions.

It is indeed true that if $a_n=0$ for all $n$ including $n=0$ then the function is odd. The easiest way to see this is to consider $f(x)+f(-x)$. It's Fourier cosine coefficients will be $2a_n=0$, and its sine coefficients vanish by a direct calculation. Hence all Fourier coefficients of $f(x)+f(-x)$, so this function is zero by the uniqueness theorem for Fourier series.

Comment: To emphasize, in case the OP missed it: The derivation of $a_0$ in the question is *wrong*. The derivation of $a_n$ for $n > 0$ is correct, though.

Comment: @fgp To me, it looked more like the calculation of $a_0$ was missing. Don't they teach that you have to treat it separately these days? But you're right that I should have been louder on this point.